# Getting Dates from the Month that no records in the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I pass the date from the view, and from the controller, I divide it and get the given date Month **start date**, and **end Date**.

Then from **StartDate** to **EndDate**, I'm checking from the database table to get the data that is available.

`Also, I want to get the dates that there are no records in the table that are given date ranges.`

Any way of getting those records to list?

This is my code that get the date range and select the data from the database for the start and end dates.

```
var startDate = new DateTime(attendanceVM.MonthYear.Year, attendanceVM.MonthYear.Month, 1);
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
int EmpId = int.Parse(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).FindFirst("UserId").Value);
IEnumerable < AttendanceResults > resutls = (from l in db.UserLog 
                                             where l.Emp_Id == EmpId && l.Login_Date >= startDate && l.Login_Date <= endDate 
                                             select new AttendanceResults {
                                                 Id = l.Id,
                                                 Date = l.Login_Date.ToString(),
                                                 Acc_Name = l.PC_User_Name,
                                                 PC_Name = l.PC_Name
                                                  
                                              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a range using `Enumerable.Range`

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days).Select(dayOffset => startDate.AddDays(dayOffset));
```

then you can use the `Except` function

```
var notInRange = range.Except(results.Select(r => r.login_Date))
```

By the way you should review the typo, the formatting and the use of a naming notation

Comment: Hi. Tried but the ``range. Except`` not allowed. Im creating a timesheet. So is there any way of displaying the month date start to end and assign the data to it from the data table that match with the date ?

Comment: Why is not allowed? Should be! https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0

Comment: error is ``Ienumerable<DateTume> does not contain a definition for ''except'' and the pest extension method overload'Queryable.Except<bool> etc..``

Comment: Try doing a `ToList()` to the `IQueryable`